# iOS Capture screen, then crop and mask the result image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, image-masking

In my application, I want to do the following steps:

1 - Capture the screen, this part is no problem for me, I'm using the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)captureScreen {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, 0.0f);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

2 - I cropped the image with this function

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect  {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return resultImage;
}
```

3 - Then I mask the cropped image with a pure black and white mask

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage  {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedRef];
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskedRef);

    return resultImage;
}
```

However, the result image I got is that outside the shape of the mask, the image is in black color instead of transparent. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem, it is due to the alpha channel of the image to be masked. So before masking, I create another UIImage with alpha channel and continue my steps.

This is the code for creating a UIImage with alpha

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithAlpha  {
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGImageRef resultImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultImageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(resultImageRef);

    return resultImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Works for me. Hope it will work for you too.

```
- (UIImage*) doImageMask:(UIImage *)mainImage:(UIImage*)maskImage{

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];

// create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


if (mainViewContentContext == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

CGFloat ratio = 0;

ratio = maskImage.size.width/ mainImage.size.width;

if(ratio * mainImage.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
    ratio = maskImage.size.height/ mainImage.size.height;
} 

CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height}};
CGRect rect2  = {{-((mainImage.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((mainImage.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {mainImage.size.width*ratio, mainImage.size.height*ratio}};

CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, mainImage.CGImage);

// Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
// release that bitmap context
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

CGImageRelease(newImage);

// return the image
return theImage;
}
```